# Submit form from a modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that lunchs a modal for confirmation before submitting, this modal has the submit button and is not inside the `<form>`, is working everywhere besides IE, in IE it just doesnt do anything.

```
<form action="" id="form" name="form" > // start form
```

In the modal this is the submit button

```
<button id="btnSend" type="submit" form="form">OK</button>
```

Tried to add a hidden submit button in the form as suggestted in other post but didnt work.

Comment: You could try posting the form with js in case of IE: `document.getElementById('form').submit()`. Just trigger this code when user clicks the modal confirmation button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `form` attribute does not supported by IE or Edge. So, you should handle click action and submit your form manually to support cross browser.

You also needs to add a hidden submit button in your form if you want end user submit form when press `enter` on input fields..

```
document.getElementById('btnSend')
    .addEventListner('click', function (event) {
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
    })
;
```

edit: Overview of Browsers supporting form-attribute [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realized that it wasn't working in edge either.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnSend', function() {
 $('#form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" id="form" name="form" onSubmit="alert('submitted')"></form>

<button id="btnSend" type="submit" form="form">OK</button>
```

Comment: You should remove `form` attribute from your submit button when you already handle it manually. Otherwise, it will submit twice on browsers which supported this attribute.

Comment: The onsubmit attribute was just to demonstrate it's actually submitting.